# Logarithmic differentials on an arithmetic surface, and Poincaré residue

Tags: reference-request, derham-cohomology, kahler-differentials, differentials, arithmetic-scheme

Suppose that $X$ is an arithmetic surface, i.e. $\pi: X \to S$ flat and relative dimension 1 over a Dedekind scheme $S$, and assume $X$ smooth.

Let $Y \subset X$ be a horizontal effective Cartier divisor.

As in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FMU,
we have the sheaves of differentials
$$\Omega_{X/S}^p \subset \Omega_{X/S}^p(\log Y) \subset \Omega_{X/S}^p(Y),$$

where $\Omega_{X/S}(\log Y)$ is generated by $\Omega_{X/S}$ and elements $\mathrm{dlog}(f) = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f}$ for local equations $f$ defining $Y$.

$Y/S$ is a finite flat extension, possible ramified, so not necessarily smooth or having normal crossing singularities.

(**1**) Do we still have the following short exact sequence of complexes?

$$0 \to \Omega_{X/S}^\bullet \to \Omega_{X/S}^\bullet(\log Y) \to \Omega_{Y/S}^\bullet[-1] \to 0$$

If not, what is the cokernel?

Would it still hold if $X$ is regular with normal crossing singularities?

(**2**) If $X/S$ is smooth, so that $\Omega_{X/S}$ is locally free, is $\Omega_{X/S}(\log Y)$ also locally free?

**Addendum**:
From [Dolgachev's article](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eidolga/arrangements.pdf) (p3), if the base $S=k$ is a field of characteristic zero, then
we get the exact sequence
$$0 \to \Omega^1_{X/k} \to \Omega^1_{X/k}(\log Y) \to \mathcal{E}xt^1_X(\mathcal{J}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_X) \to 0$$
where $\mathcal{J}_Y$ is the Jacobian ideal of $Y$ (generated locally by $f,f'$).
The ideal $\mathcal{J}_Y$ defines a closed subscheme $Y^s$ supported on the singular locus of $Y$ (i.e. ramification locus in my case), and we have $\mathcal{O}_{Y^s} = \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}_Y$.

Then some more analysis gives
$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{E}xt^1_X(\mathcal{J}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{E}xt^2_X(\mathcal{O}_{Y^s},\mathcal{O}_X) \to 0.$$
Apparently it is known that the $\mathcal{E}xt^q_X(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_X)$ will vanish if $q<c$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is supported on a closed subset of codimension $c$. Unfortunately in my case the codimension of the singular locus will be $2$, so I can't draw any immediate conclusions.

The reframing in terms of Ext sheaves provides more information, but unfortunately I still have some problems:
(a) The results stated by Dolgachev are only over a field, and I am unsure whether they work over a Dedekind domain $S$,
(b) I don't know enough about Ext sheaves to gain anything from this analysis.

I would appreciate any help or insight here.