# When is a sheaf $\mathcal{L}_1 \subset \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{L}_2$ sandwiched between two line bundles also a line bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, line-bundles, flatness, invertible-sheaves

This question is in the interest of answering one part of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418209/logarithmic-differentials-on-an-arithmetic-surface-and-poincar%C3%A9-residue), but I think it is distinct enough to warrant a separate question.

Let $X$ be a regular 2-dimensional Noetherian scheme, for example an arithmetic surface $\pi:X \to S$.

Suppose we have line bundles $\mathcal{L}_1, \mathcal{L}_2$ and a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ satisying
$$\mathcal{L}_1 \subset \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{L}_2.$$

**Question**: When can we conclude that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free?

As submodules of a locally free sheaf on a smooth curve are locally free, this would hold if $X$ were a smooth curve. We do know at least that it is torsion-free.

Really the most important thing I need to know is when $\mathcal{F}$ will preserve exactness of sequences
$$0 \to \mathcal{L}' \to \mathcal{L} \to \overline{\mathcal{L}} \to 0$$
$$0 \dashrightarrow \mathcal{L}'\otimes\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{L}\otimes\mathcal{F} \to \overline{\mathcal{L}}\otimes\mathcal{F} \to 0$$

for line bundles $\mathcal{L}', \mathcal{L}$.

So flatness would suffice. But by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_module#Finitely_presented,_finitely_related,_and_coherent_modules)
I believe flat is equivalent to projective in this situation.

In lieu of flatness, a characterization of the $\mathcal{L}$ for which $\mathcal{T}or_1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{F})$ vanishes could potentially satisfy my needs, but knowing $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free would be preferable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is too vague. And as @user1092847 explained, typically such $F$ is not locally free (essentially, the condition that $F$ contains a locally free subsheaf is non-restrictive).

Comment: Here's a geometric condition. Like others, I'm not sure what you want, so I don't know if it's good for you. Note that $\mathcal{L_2}/\mathcal{L_1}$ is supported on some divisor $D$. Also, $\overline{\mathcal{L}}$ is supported on another divisor $\widetilde{D}$. It seems to me you're okay if $D$ and $\widetilde{D}$ intersect transversally in their smooth loci.

Comment: @sdr Thank you. This is along the lines of the conditions I am looking for, but unfortunately in my case the two divisors will be the same divisor $D$. I was hoping the fact that it is integral (reduced + irreducible) would be enough to draw a conclusion, but I suppose it's not.

Comment: "Almost never" would be a reasonable answer. For any fixed $\mathcal L_1 \subset \mathcal L_2$, there are only finitely many line bundles between them, but usually infinitely many non-line bundles.

Comment: @WillSawin Ok, this is interesting, and verily dashes my hopes. Can you provide a rationale or reference for that fact?

Comment: There's no reference, but it's easy: Fix a meromorphic section $s$ of $\mathcal L_1$ and look at its divisor as a section of $\mathcal L_1, \mathcal F, \mathcal L_2$. If  $\mathcal F$ is a line bundle, the divisor of $\mathcal F$ is sandwiched between the divisor of $\mathcal L_1$ and $\mathcal L_2$, but these differ on only finitely many irreducible components, so there are only finitely many possibilities.

Comment: For the other way, we are lookiong for submodules of $\mathcal L_2/\mathcal L_1$, which is a sheaf supported on a curve. As long as this curve is nonempty, it is easy to see there are infinitely many submodules - e.g. the submodule of sections vanishing on some finite set of points. Only finitely many can have inverse image in $\mathcal L_2$ a line bundle.

Comment: @WillSawin This clears things up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Locally, $\mathcal L_2$ is isomorphic to the coordinate ring $R$ and $\mathcal F$ is an ideal $I \subseteq R$  which contains a principal ideal. So, e.g $R = k[x,y]$ and $I = (x,y)$  containing $(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal I think you should specify what kind of conditions would you expect to impose.

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal That's fair, I misread.  However, the point is that *any* ideal contains a principal ideal-- so being sandwiched between two line bundles tells you nothing more than $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal L_2$.  Basically, you are asking when an ideal is (locally) principal.  $M$ being an ideal ideal forces the depth to be $\geq 1$,  but you need to be depth $2$ to be a free module/flat.

Comment: @user1092847 Thank you. It looks I may need to find a different approach to solve my problem.